# How to prove (using integration by parts)

Tags: calculus, integration

Could you help to prove this:

$$Y(\lambda) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x) e^{i \lambda   f(x)} \,dx$$

we should use integration by parts to get
$$Y(\lambda) = \frac{1}{i \lambda }e^{i \lambda   f(x)} \frac{g(x)}{f'(x)}\bigg\vert _{a}^{b}-\frac{1}{i \lambda }\int_{a}^{b} dx \ e^{i \lambda   f(x)} \frac{d}{dx} \bigg[\frac{g(x)}{f'(x)}\bigg] $$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is $\int_a^b g(x)e^{i\lambda f(x)}dx$. When you see e raised to the power of something, it's usually going to be set to the dv term in the integration by parts. Let's use

$$\begin{matrix}u=g(x)&dv=e^{i\lambda f(x)}dx\\du=g'(x)dx&v=\frac{1}{i\lambda f'(x)}e^{i\lambda f(x)}.\end{matrix}$$

By the integration by parts formula, we have:

$$\begin{split}uv|_{a}^b-\int_a^b v du&=\frac{1}{i\lambda}\frac{g(x)}{f'(x)}e^{i\lambda f(x)}|_{a}^b-\frac{1}{i\lambda}\int_a^b \frac{\frac{d}{dx}g(x)}{f'(x)}e^{i\lambda f(x)}dx.\end{split}$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$\int_{a}^{b} g(x) e^{i \lambda   f(x)} \,dx$$ we set
\begin{align}
u &= g(x), &&du = g'(x)\,dx\\
dv &= e^{i \lambda   f(x)}\,dx, &&\phantom{d}v = \frac{1}{f'(x)i\lambda}e^{i \lambda   f(x)}.
\end{align}

This then gives us
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b} g(x) e^{i \lambda   f(x)} \,dx &= uv\bigg|_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}v\,du\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{i\lambda}e^{i \lambda   f(x)}\frac{g(x)}{f'(x)}\bigg|_{a}^{b} - \frac{1}{i\lambda}\int_{a}^{b}e^{i \lambda   f(x)}\frac{g'(x)}{f'(x)}\,dx.
\end{align}

Note that this is close, but not the same as what you have, so I suspect there is either a typo in what you entered or in your original source.